# Insert a string with numbers and characters into an integer type in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to set up the mapping for an index to allow an integer field be populated by strings. However, this isn't a simple parsing solution as the strings I will be inserting are not clean. For example, I'm trying to store disk usage as an integer field, but the data I will be getting are string's such as '320GB'. Is there a way to remove the 'GB' and make it easier to parse so it can be stored as an integer?

I've already looked at [coercing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html) but it understandably failed to parse the string into an integer. I've looked at the [convert processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/convert-processor.html) but it seems this can only be used during reindexing operations.

TLDR: How would I go about inserting the following data as an integer type into Elasticsearch:
320GB, 100GB, 50MB, 140KB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `convert` processor can help you here... it's converting the data types (ie from `string` to `integer`) but in your case the string is alpha characters that cannot be converted to a numeric data type.

I would, instead, look into the [`grok` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/grok-processor.html) and only  "catch" the numbers in the provided value, OR (and this I think is better since it's flattening the values into a commong unit of measure - the byte) look into the [`bytes` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/bytes-processor.html).